# Android - add a view that will exist despite setContentView()

Tags: android, view

Anytime one calls `setContentView()` multiple times, previous views get destroyed. How does one create a view that will exist, as an overlay or under the main window, despite multiple calls to `setContentView()`?

Comment: Can you provide a small example to illustrate what you are trying to do? In particular, show when you want to call `setContentView()`.

Comment: I simply use many layouts for single activity and I change them with setContentView.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I'll answer myself: After some reading I believe I shouldn't be calling `setContentView` multiple times. 
Instead I should use one layout that has the view I wanted to exist despite layout changes and also put `ViewFlipper` and use that for layout changes not `setContentView`.